# /usr/bin/python Replacement

Tags: script, python, ubuntu-12.04

If I've changed the target of `/usr/bin/python` from `/usr/bin/python2.7` to `/usr/bin/python3.2` (I realize this was an ***ABSOUTELY HORRIBLE*** idea) in Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS. Afterwards, several applications, including `software-center` and `update-manager` have stopped working. Insofar as I can tell, this is because they are written in Python2.7. I replaced the default `/usr/bin/python` shebang with the 2.7 one, and this fixes them on the application level. Switching `/usr/bin/python` back to `/usr/bin/python2.7` really isn't an option, but is there a list of all applications installed by default in Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS, if installed from a new CD-R, that use a shebang of `#!/usr/bin/python` instead of `#!/usr/bin/pythonX.Y`?

Comment: grep ^\#\!/usr/bin/python / -R    -- but bear in mind this won't work, as many will use #!/usr/bin/env python

Comment: "Switching /usr/bin/python back to /usr/bin/python2.7 really isn't an option". Why isn't it? You can always use python3.2 in the shebang if you need it for a specific app.

Answer (score 1):

You could boot from a live-CD then grep the files in `/usr/bin` to find what uses Python.

But **what do you want to achieve** with that? Many applications haven't been ported to Python 3, often due to the lack of libraries: many don't have a Python 3 version yet, or it's still buggy. You're asking for troubles.

If you just want to use Python 3 for your programs, you can use the shebang `#!/usr/bin/python3.2` or  `#!/usr/bin/env python3.2`.